# difficulty accessing yaml node as an array

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I was trying to access a frame that has X and Y co-ordinates using yaml. Things were working fine when I had `&frame_node` instead of `*frame_node`, but for using the `FindValue` function I had to use `*frame_node`. However, `frame_node[0]`, `frame_node[1]`, etc., give me an error now. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

```
if (const YAML::Node *frame_node = config_node.FindValue("frame")) {
   //const YAML::Node &frame_node = config_node["frame"];
   std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
   hasCard = 1 ; 
   // X-coordinates.
   frame_node[0] >> x[0];
   frame_node[1] >> x[1];
   frame_node[2] >> x[2];
   frame_node[3] >> x[3];
   // Y-coordinates.
   frame_node[4] >> y[0];
   frame_node[5] >> y[1];
   frame_node[6] >> y[2];
   frame_node[7] >> y[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`frame_node` is a pointer, so `frame_node[1]` will give you pointer arithmetic. You want `(*frame_node)[1]`.